# JPA entries are not created or retrieved

Tags: java, database, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I'm having program that creates JPA entries with the entity manager.
during the process I **don't get any errors**.

```
...
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("perst");
EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(object);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

...

entityManager.close();
```

I have created a program like follows to read the data but it doesn't return any data,
the query returns empty. What could be the reason ?

This is the program to read the data:

```
static List<String> classList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("perst");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

        classList.add("LeaveRequest");
        classList.add("person");

        for (Object classOjc : classList) {

            String className = classOjc.toString();

            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + className + " p");

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            List resultList = query.getResultList();

            System.out.println(resultList.size());

            for (Object result : resultList) {

                System.out.println(result.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

the xml persist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">


    <persistence-unit name="perst" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>LeaveRequest</class>
        <class>person</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:derby:/home/vogella/databases/simpleDb;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="Sales" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: If you don't get any error, and the size of the lists returned is 0, then it simply means there is nothing in these tables. Which database are youusing? Do you recreate the schema each time you start the application?

Comment: First of all I would suggest you to write a JUnit test instead of this logic above. Also it would be nice to see your `persistence.xml` to see the configuration.

Comment: @JBNizet- i dont get the error while im entering the data so i guess that the entries should be persist...,(if no i think i fail in the commit)there is a way during the entries creation to verify that the process succeeded ? the DB is derby with eclipselink

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth-edited my post with the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured eclipselink to drop and recreate the schema each time the app is started:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
```

So obviously, if you run a first application that persists some entries, and then a second application which tries to read what the first one has written, you won't find anything anymore, since eclipselink drops everything and recreates the schema every time.